Why using mutual information is allowed for feature selection if depends on the "scale" of entropies?
It is common to use mutual information as feature selection method. However, I fail to see why this is the case, since the mutual information $I(X, Y)$ depends on both entropies $H(X)$ and $H(Y)$ via the formula:
$$ I(X, Y) = H(X) + H(Y) - H(X,Y)$$
meaning that comparing $I(X_i, Y)$ and $(X_j, Y)$ as a measure for selecting between $X_i$ and $X_j$ is not straightforward since the measure can be bloated by the marginal entropies. It is like selecting between $X_i$ and $X_j$ based on the covariance with $Y$ instead of correlation.
The only way I can think that such a comparison is allowed is due to the equivalent formula:
$$I(X, Y) = H(Y) - H(Y|X)$$
As the first term $H(Y)$ is the same for all $X_i$ then the ramking shouldn't depend on the "scale" of $H(Y)$. Is that correct or am I missing something?

Harrell says that feature selection is the enemy of prediction, so it stands to reason if this should be done at all.


Mutual information is not modified by any affine transform of $X$ (or any bijective transform of $X$ for that matter). This follows immediately from the definition when both $X,Y$ are discrete. It's not obvious when they are continuous (and I'm not actually sure whether you might need an additional condition in the continuous case).

Mutual information is tricky to estimate, no? Do you have examples of people using it to perform variable selection?



Here is an example from scikit-learn.

With regards to 1., please note that by "scale" of entropies I mean the magnitude $H(X_i)$ not the scale of $X_i$.
